# How to create a coding sandbox with cloud functions for executing users code on the server? Dos/don'ts?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am working on a project similar to Codecademy and doing some research on how to execute potentially malicious user code. I can run html, css and js on the client side but I will need to execute code on the server for compiled languages.

For those who are not familiar with Codecademy, it is an interactive website that teaches users how to code. There are some coding challenges and users enter their solution which is executed on the server with test cases. If the code passes tests user is allowed to continue with the next challenge. As you may guess my biggest concern is executing user code on server side.

I think the best way to secure my backend is creating layers and using containers to separate compilers from the rest of the server. My plan is creating microservices for each programming language. I am planning to do that with (gcp or aws) cloud functions.

After those parts I am lost. I think I should instantiate containers with docker and run the users' code in that containers with tests and return the result to the main server. Assuming that would be straightforward with docker images (or using something like [compilebox](https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox)) but I am not sure about the performance. Because every time a solution sent, a container will be built from scratch and after running the code it will be destroyed. My second concern is payment plan of cloud functions. I somehow need to limit users access to the service since I do not want to pay millions for the server cost.

Since I have no experience with cloud functions I am not sure if this is a valid plan. Should I go with micro services or should I create a classic monolithic backend. If you have any other ideas or suggestions please feel free to share. If my idea is valid, please help me with dos and don'ts regarding the case.

Note: I am using Node on the backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

google's [katacoda](https://www.katacoda.com/) offers an embedded shell in your site:

```
<script src="//katacoda.com/embed.js"></script>
<div id="katacoda-scenario-1"
    data-katacoda-id="<username>/<scenario-name>"
    data-katacoda-color="004d7f"
    style="height: 600px; padding-top: 20px;"></div>
```

https://www.katacoda.com/embed

may turn up very useful in your case.

this kinda solutions sounds much easy and secure than building your own sandbox,

lots of luck!